# I am having trouble printing out the right output of numbers for this Data Structure using a for loop and a while loop

Tags: java, loops, data-structures

using a for loop for printCount() and whileLoop for printWhileCount() if the number n is being added to is divisible by 2, the output is 1/2 the number plus n, if it's divisible by 3, the output is 0, and if it's anything else, the output is the number.

the printCount() function and the
printWhileCount()output should be
5 1 6 0 7 5 8 7 9 0,
5 1 6 0 7 5 8 7 9 0

instead the output is
10 8 12 9 0 10 16 11 18 12,
10 8 12 9 0 10 16 11 18 12

This is my code

```
public class HelloPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printCount(5);
        printCountWhile(5);
    }

    public static void printCount(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int num = i + n;
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print((num / 2) + n + " ");
            } else if (num % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("0 ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(num + n + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void printCountWhile(int n) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            int num = i + n;
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print((num / 2) + n + " ");
            } else if (num % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("0 ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(num + n + " ");
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: Why should the second number be 1? Clearly `num` is 6 at that moment, so how do you get from 6 to output 1?

Comment: 3 is divisible by 3 so the output would be 0 + the int n which would output 1

Comment: Where do you get the 3 from?

Comment: whoops, I mean 6 is divisible by 3 so the output is 0 + int n which is 1

Comment: But you wrote in the question that if it is divisible by 3 the output should be just 0 -- nothing else? Why do you expect to add `n` here?

Comment: for this example printCount() parameters are set to 5 and the same for printWhileCount()

Comment: So the entire code starts at 5

Comment: Yes, but in the second iteration, i=1 and n=5, so num=6. How do you get from there to output 1????

Comment: that's the issue I don't know my professor asked me to code the program that produces that output, but I don't know how he is getting that output

Comment: OK, then we can't help you. You should ask your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

The description you give does not correspond to the desired output. I guess you should not calculate `num`, but should apply the logic to `i`:

```
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print((i / 2) + n + " ");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("0 ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
```

The corrected description should then be:

> if the <strike>number n is being added to</strike> **index** is divisible by 2, the output is 1/2 the <strike>number</strike> **index** plus n, if it's divisible by 3, the output is 0, and if it's anything else, the output is the <strike>number</strike> **index**.